# Excel date formula needed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm missing some knowledge using date conditions.  The following would calculate the amount of Late fee if insufficient payment is entered in E1

Late Fee Cell  D1:   IF on 03/08/13 cell F1 is equal to Zero, then 0, else F1 * 5% and if on 3/16/13 F1*10%

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SuperUser! The following formula entered in cell D1 will produce the late fee amounts that you want.

The formula assumes that the due date is entered in cell A1, the payment date in B1, the balance due before payment in cell C1, and a lookup table for the late fee rates in cells A9:B12.

```
  =IF(F1>0,LOOKUP(MAX(B1-A1,0),$A$9:$A$12,$B$9:$B$12))*MAX(F1,0)
```

It also accommodates two possibilities that you did not mention explicitly, but are certain to happen now and then:

- Early payments
- Overpayments

(Although the unpaid balance that is subject to the late fee shown in F1 will go negative if there is an overpayment (because the balance is calculated as the simple difference of cells E1 and C1), the late fee itself applies only to the case where that balance is positive.)

[image: Late fee calculation]

Comment: “Welcome to Stack Overflow!”?  :-)

Comment: Asleep at the wheel again:(

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've worked out what you're asking.

This needs a cell where the Due Date sits.  I have assumed that cell is B1.
I have also assumed that the percent increase stops after 10%.  If that is not the case, then a VLookup solution will work better.

The formula needed in cell D1 that calculates the late fee (based on the amount outstanding in cell F1):

```
=IF(TODAY()<B1,0,IF(TODAY()-7<B1, 0.05*F1, 0.1*F1))
```

If you need to keep bumping up the rate after next week, the week after etc, edit the question and I'll add a VLookup solution